# Converting a cURL command to .NET

Tags: .net, curl

Hi have the following cURL command that I would like to convert to VB.NET or C#.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users \-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \ -d '{"login": "eddard@company.com", "name": "Ned Stark"}' \ -X POST
```

I've tried the following in VB.NET:

```
Dim url As String = "https://api.box.com/2.0/users"
Dim wrq = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
Dim postString As String = "login=eddard@company.com&name=Ned Stark"

wrq.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " & o2ses.AccessToken)
wrq.Method = "POST"
wrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
wrq.ContentLength = postString.Length

Dim wrqWriter As New StreamWriter(wrq.GetRequestStream())
wrqWriter.Write(postString)
wrqWriter.Close()

Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(wrq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
```

I am a newb to cURL and to using HttpWebRequest in .NET, but have converted cURL commands to .NET before (thanks to this site :)), but none with the -d option in them, so I'm kind of lost.  It keeps returning error 400 (bad request) when the line below is executed.

```
Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(wrq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
```

I think it has to do with what data I am sending (i.e. it's not getting the proper 'login' and 'name' parameters it needs).

Any help is appreciated.  I can try to provide more information if needed.  As mentioned, I'm a newb to this, so I'll try my best.

Thanks!

Comment: Your post string should be url encoded (see HttpUtility.UrlEncode() or an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703032/99256) for starters.

Comment: Thanks for the response and link.  I modified the code to define 'poststring' as stringbuilder and appended the urlencoded data but I still get a 'bad request (400)' from the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know vb.net but I think that the authorization header should look like this:

```
wrq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " & o2ses.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've changed the line recommended but still the same results.

Comment: I would recommend then to install Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/home) and have a look at requests from your application ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935181/how-to-view-the-headers-sent-by-httpwebrequest). This way you can compare headers from your .NET application and headers from curl.