# Selenium C# - HttpWebRequest always returns 404 despite sites being browse-able

Tags: c#, selenium, http-status-code-404, httpwebrequest

I've created a test that checks for broken links on our website. I collect a list of links from our website's site map and in a loop, perform a HttpWebRequest which fails the test if one or more links returns anything but OK (200). The links that fail are added to a dictionary for later review (status code, link).

Initially I was getting authorisation errors, so I added the relevant code to get through our proxy. Now, all HttpWebRequests return 404 - not just to our website, but to any website - Google/Twitter/Facebook etc. However, all of the links work in a browser. I've tried to monitor the traffic in Fiddler while running the test, but no entries are appearing in the Fiddler stream.

On the assumption that this is a 'me'/'us' problem, rather than a fault with the HttpWebRequest class, I suspect that I am not making a fully qualified/'legitimate' HttpWebRequest.

I've gone down the route of checking the headers, re: [How to view the headers sent by HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935181/how-to-view-the-headers-sent-by-httpwebrequest) but I'm not getting anywhere with that. When I query the request headers on http://rextester.com, it's empty. I only get headers on the response...

```
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        Console.WriteLine("Request headers: " + myHttpWebRequest.Headers);
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Response code: " + myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Response headers: " + myHttpWebResponse.Headers);
```

Here's the code I'm using in my test, is there anything obviously amiss here? The commented out lines were an attempt to specify headers to fix this, on the assumption I was missing something that needed to be in the request, but they made no difference.

```
    public void BrowseEachLinkOnPage(string page)
    {
        // Page factory does not recognise lists as IWebElement or IList<IWebElement> despite them being set as such. Resorting to manual collection of elements...

        // Default collection to initialise variable, //*[text()='donotfindthis'] should find 0 elements
        var linksToTest = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[text()='donotfindthis']"));

        try
        {
            switch (page)
            {
                case "site map":
                    linksToTest = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'sitemap__container')]//a[contains(@href,'/')]"));
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.UpdateTestStatus(Log.Status.Failed, "BrowseEachLinkOnPage(): - \"" + page + "\" page does not map to a predefined list of links. Check existing or create a new reference to a list of links.", driver);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        Dictionary<object, string> invalidHttpRequestResponses = new Dictionary<object, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> httpRequestExceptions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int numberOfHttpRequestExceptions = 0;
        int numberOfLinksToTest = linksToTest.Count();

        if (numberOfLinksToTest > 0)
        {
            // An exception is triggered if an exception occurs within the loop at least once
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLinksToTest; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest httpReq =
                            (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(linksToTest[i].GetAttribute("href"));
                        //httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                        httpReq.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                        // AD credentials required to get through proxy, enter password when testing
                        httpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");

                        WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://10.0.0.0/myproxy.pac")
                        {
                            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword")
                        };

                        httpReq.Proxy = webProxy;

                        //httpReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                        //httpReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                        //httpReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";

                        HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse) httpReq.GetResponse();

                        if (httpRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
invalidHttpRequestResponses.Add(httpRes.StatusCode, linksToTest[i].GetAttribute("href"));
                        }

                        httpRes.Close();
                    }
                    // Suppress the exception, instead capture the details of the exception for later use
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        numberOfHttpRequestExceptions += 1;
                        httpRequestExceptions.Add(i, e.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            // Report why the HttpWebRequests failed for further troubleshooting
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.UpdateTestStatus(Log.Status.Failed, "HttpWebRequest failed: " + numberOfHttpRequestExceptions + " exception(s) out of " + numberOfLinksToTest + " links tested.\n----- Attempt, exception: -----\n" + httpRequestExceptions, driver);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.UpdateTestStatus(Log.Status.Failed, "BrowseEachLinkOnPage(): - there are no links in the collection.", driver);
            throw new Exception("BrowseEachLinkOnPage(): - there are no links in the collection.");
        }

        // Assuming there were no HttpWebRequest exceptions, report on any links that failed (StatusCode != to OK)
        if (invalidHttpRequestResponses.Count > 0)
        {
            Log.UpdateTestStatus(Log.Status.Failed, "HttpWebRequest: - invalid response on pages (response, URL):\n" + invalidHttpRequestResponses, driver);
            throw new Exception("HttpWebRequest: - invalid response on pages (response, URL):\n" + invalidHttpRequestResponses);
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: Why don't you just navigate through all links?

Comment: I am, by collecting the links for the site from the site map page. The collection of links works fine, it's only the HttpWebRequest that is giving an unexpected result. I even ran a List<string> for five external sites, same error. I've raised a query with tech support to see if there's a block on the network for HttpWebRequests.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the wrong proxy, our tech support has enlightened me.